# Office Communicator 2007 send message from javascript

Tags: javascript, office-communicator

I'm trying to open an OC chat via a link.
Currently working with code like this:

```
window.open("sip:name@domain.com");
```

But I would like a custom message, the same way it works with emails

```
window.location  = "mailto:email@address.com?Subject=subject&body=body";
```

So it may look like this:

```
window.open("sip:name@domain.com?message=messageText");
```

Is it possible?